# Missing '()' invoking a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below to return the current year ([I also have it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/c7qGn/)). jsFiddle keeps giving me an error: "Missing '()' invokes a constructor", and I don't know what it means or how to get rid of it. The code still works, but I'd like to know what the heck is causing the error:

HTML:

jQuery:

```
var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#year").text(currentYear);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use new Date()

Comment: Out of interest, where are you seeing that error message? In the console? And what browser are you using? (I don't see it in either Chrome or IE)

Comment: (didn't see this comment here!) when you click the JSHint button at the top of the page, red dots appear beside any errors that are present. Hover over the red dot to see what the error is. It's a great tool for new folks like myself! (Chrome)

Comment: This is a good Q&A and should not have been downvoted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is the `new Date` part that is causing the warning. This will fix it:

```
var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

Comment: A valid question with a good answer. Why the question is downvoted?

Comment: @Blaise not being able to identify the constructor in that code block fails the minimum-understanding test. (I did not vote.)

Comment: wow... for a guy just learning... guess I gotta learn before I can learn! Thanks for the help @musefan, that did the trick!

Comment: @leftside: [Codecademy is a great resource](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) for learning the basics in javascript. Might be worth checking it out when you have some spare time

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I have checked that a bit, and this site is great too - folks are quick to answer.

Comment: btw this is a matter of code style, not an error; `new Date` is valid JS and identical to `new Date()`.

Comment: @musefan `new Date` has always been valid JS and won't cause any errors. The OP's problem was a warning from JSHint, not an error from running the code. Nevertheless I'm glad it was resolved. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the brackets for `Date`, it should be `Date()`

So:

```
var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a parentheses

```
new Date()
```